# How to read a method call

Tags: methods, vocabulary

I have a mostly vocabulary-related question, concerning method calls:

when you have a code such as

```
dog.sit()
```

Would you rather say that you "call the sit method **of** dog" or "call the sit method **on** dog?" and why?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

Given the choices you provide and in the case you gave, I would probably say "on" because it's being called on a specific instance. If it were a static method at the class level, then I would probably use "of". But in reality, I say "call dog dot sit" when I'm actually talking to someone ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't make people think.  Just say what you see `dog dot sit`

Answer (score 0):

I would say either "dog dot sit" or "dog, sit"